# Merge different web services to one port

Tags: redirect, flask, port, lighttpd

I have different web services running on different port (on one Linux host):

```
https://host.com:101/app1/ (Flask)
https://host.com:102/app2/ (Ruby)
...
```

How can I access them through a common port (80), so the port could be hidden?

```
https://host.com/app1/
https://host.com/app2/
...
```

Content is HTML based only, HTTPS is required.
I would prefer lighttpd for the glue logic if possible.

Comment: Yes, lighttpd can do this.  Please see the documentation for lighttpd mod_proxy: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

Comment: unfortunately it says: lighttpd mod_proxy does not currently support SSL/TLS

Comment: lighttpd supports SSL/TLS.  mod_proxy supports connecting to *backends* via HTTP, but does not support connecting to *backends* using SSL/TLS.  Typical use of lighttpd is to sit in front of these services, also running on the local machine, or else located in a local pod on the same network.